# Eclipse Scout Tool button not show image on RAP

Tags: button, icons, eclipse-scout

I see [this tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/ToolButton), and create abstract form tool button. But in RAP I can't configure the icon image.

My tool button is like this :

```
 @Order(10.0)
public class TestPageTool extends AbstractFormToolButton {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredIconId() {

    return Icons.EclipseScout;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredText() {

    return TEXTS.get("TestPage");
  }
}
```

and the result is :

[image]

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this topic on the scout Forum: [Toolbar doesn't show any Icons](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1065300&goto=1690876&#msg_1690876)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be found in the **widgets** demo application ([live demo](http://In%20the%20RAP%20client,%20you%20also%20need%20to%20customize%20the%20CSS,%20to%20bind%20the%20icon%20defined%20in%20the%20RAP%20Bundle%20with%20the%20Tool%20Button:%20org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/application.css), [source](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/tree/4.0/widgets), [about](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Demo#Widgets))

The images are defined twice:

- Client (used in the desktop client):

  - [org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client/resources/icons/star_red.png](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client/resources/icons/star_red.png)
  - [org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client/resources/icons/star_red.png](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.client/resources/icons/star_yellow.png)
- RAP Bundle (used for the RAP client):

  - [org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/img/button/tool/star_red.png](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/img/button/tool/star_red.png)
  - [org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/img/button/tool/star_yellow.png](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/img/button/tool/star_yellow.png)

In the RAP client, you also need to customize the CSS, to bind the icon defined in the RAP Bundle with the Tool Button. Check the content of `application.css` to have an example:

[org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/application.css](https://github.com/BSI-Business-Systems-Integration-AG/org.eclipsescout.demo/blob/4.0/widgets/org.eclipsescout.demo.widgets.ui.rap/theme/application.css)